# Jenkins job dependency/relationship

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

We are using jenkins for CI and have some complex jobs interdependent.I just want to represent graphically or in any other way the dependencies of jobs.I investigated and installed dependency graph with graphviz representation but its giving too complex figures.Any one know any other plugins?

Comment: It should be possible to look at a job depending graph in graphviz which might reduce the size of the graph significantly. Still not the best solution, but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

Consider some view plugins :

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin (shows you dependency chains)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin (shows you dependency chains that affected previous runs)

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins recently [added](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/workflow-plugin-10) first class support for workflow.  Written and supported by Kohsuke.

Comment: This appears to be a plugin for creating workflows (i.e. not using normal dependency trees), not viewing existing ones [?]